# Hibernate criteria parameter binding

Tags: hibernate

In the below criteria, in the restriction, `"post"` is hard coded, what if we 
want to pass it as a parameter, how to set parameters with criteria, 
something like `criteria.setParameter();`

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Post.class)
.add(Restrictions.eq("title", "post")) // here post is hardcoded instead can we bind param
```

Comment: Where and how you are calling it ? Please post your full code.

Comment: As the caller of the Hibernate code is already fully parameterizable, why not just `String title = "post"; [...] add(Restrictions.eq("title", title));`

Comment: @Smutje thank you,yes I understand but is there any way to set parameters in the criteria

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this level of indirection?